# How to get login status of any website using powershell

Tags: powershell

i am trying to get login status of any website using passed parameter, My below script is returning always status code =  200 irrespective of wrong username/password.

Can anyone guide me pls?

```
$url = "{url here}"
$username = "{username here}"
$password = "{password here}"
    
$b = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username + ":" + $password)
$p = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)
    
$creds = "Basic " + $p
    
$req1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers @{"Authorization" = $creds } 
    
    
$StatusCode = [int] $req1.StatusCode;
$StatusDescription = $req1.StatusDescription;
    
       
write-host $StatusCode
write-host $StatusDescription
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for many websites. If we discard SSO websites, most will have a form login (some might work with basic auth but I don't think that's the case). The best way to handle that, from my experience, is to create a IE com object, load the website, manipulate the DOM to fill the fields and submit the form. You can make the IE object invisible so there's nothing on screen (On the plus side, you can make it visible to debug / inspect the site when first setting that up). Also look into  [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the Request / Response headers.

Comment: There is not an universal simple script to login on all websites. There's already many answers on SO on many different way to do it but it really is depenfent on the website. As for the 200, if the URL you are doing the request is authorized for users that are not logged, you will get a 200. You'd need to hit an URL restricted to logged in user that does not do a redirect to get your 401. Otherwise you're just hitting the redirected page with success.

Comment: Thanks @SagePourpre,  actually i need to achieve it for SSO websites  only, can you guide me on this?